# Why interrupt key ctl+c is active during OS boot up on ubuntu 22.04 any reason for not disabling during OS boot up process?

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

When OS boots up on ubuntu 22.04 LTS, when ctl+c is pressed it halts or re-runs the installation. Any reason why ctl+c is not disabled? Can cons of considering enabling it?

When the user presses by mistake ctl+c it would rather halt the installation or re-run the installation during this phase.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [ubuntu.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).